# Generating permutations corresponding to periodic lattice translations in c++

Tags: c++, permutation

Suppose I have a sequence of characters (ABCDEF....), in an array or a string or any suitable data structure, and these characters are distributed over the sites if a 3D lattice, such that position 1 corresponds to coordinates (1,1,1) and so on. When I perform any operation on this lattice, i.e., periodic translation in x-direction which means all elements are shifted cyclically  in the direction of  x, this should alter the sequence of characters in my data structure accordingly. My question: which data structures/functions/libraries can do these permutations efficiently in c++? Speed is important because this has to be done many times.

Comment: What's "accordingly" in this case?

Comment: Could you give an example of the operation to clarify what kind of shift you mean?

Comment: @Andreas Brinck For example, if position (3,1,1) corresponds to the 7th element in my sequence, then for a shift in the x-direction by 2 positions, the first element in the sequence should be shifted to the 7th element, and similarly for all other elements.

Comment: @thiton: an example is given in the question and my reply to Andreas Brinck

Answer (score 0):

In 1D, you could think about it as a circular doubly linked list.  The advantage would be that you could use an [STL list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) container and make your life easier.

The exercise of extending this to 3D is left to the reader.

Comment: Please don't propogate links to cplusplus.com. It's not a good resource.